# npm install fsevents errors

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello i'am trying to install fsevents whitch **npm**. Therefore i use the following versions:

- Node : 4.2.6
- NPM  : 3.5.2
- OS   : Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

  i 'am executing the statement

**Edited**

```
npm install fsevents --no-optional --save react-redux
```

after executing i get the following errors back in the console

**Edited**

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "fsevents" "--no-
optional" "--save" "react-redux"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or  
architecture: fsevents@1.0.15
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/erik/git/test/npm-debug.log
```

Please can you help fix this problem.

Manny thanks

Erik

Comment: The error is pretty clear... it doesn't support Linux. `Not compatible with your operating system or  
architecture: fsevents@1.0.15`

Comment: To expand on @JoeClay's comment, `fsevents` is a mac-only file watching package.

Comment: ???  Same porblem, but the answer do not help.  We see that npm install OSX package on Ubuntu OS.  The question is why and how to fix this ?

Comment: How can one exclude optional dependency `fsevents` from from an `npm install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments above tell you what you already know. Perhaps you should've phrased this as a question. :-)

Assuming the question is how to prevent fserrors on a non-Mac system, the solution I found is this:

Remove fserrors from your package.json and remove the folder.

`rm -r ./node_modules/fserrors`

Then run:

`npm rebuild`

Problem solved.

Comment: I do not see any `/node_modules/fserrors` in my setup. Also, my package.json does not contain `fserrors`. How do I get it resolved?

Comment: Asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929196/how-to-solve-npm-install-throwing-fsevents-warning-on-non-mac-os

Answer (score 3):

I added the following to my **package.json** file:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
  "fsevents": "2.1.2"
},
```

Then run *npm rebuild* (or wait for the next time you need the npm command) and the warning is gone.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed a similar error in my system was following this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49892996/12553428). Essentially, you can run:

`npm i --force`

from your terminal, it will install all your dependencies.