# NodeJs fs.watch/FSWatcher Error

Tags: node.js, npm, fsevents, fswatch, ubuntu-17.04

Hello I Use the following,

Ubuntu 17.04
Node: v6.11.2
NPM: v3.10.10

While installing My project dependencies I get warning on installing fsevents([this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671567/npm-install-fsevents-errors). I ignored that and I ran the project using Gulp.

I get the following error,

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: watch /media/app/modules/services/auth/ ENOSPC
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1443:19)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1470:11)
    at Gaze._watchDir (/media/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:289:30)
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:358:10
    at iterate (/media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:61:11
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:420:5
    at iterate (/media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:61:11
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:420:5
    at iterate (/media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:61:11
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/gaze.js:420:5
    at iterate (/media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:52:5)
    at /media/node_modules/gaze/lib/helper.js:61:11
```

I get this only in this machine I am using. The projects runs well on other systems.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: You may need to increase the number of files that can be watched simultaneously. See this: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/214#issuecomment-114362402

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this problem for most of my project when running with gulp. Only way I could get through was restarting my system again. But then found the root cause and a fix in the below article.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3254#issuecomment-297214395

The command to fix this problem is

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```