# why sometimes npm install is not working on mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, scrypt

I have  created nodejs project when i am running command **npm install** it is failing with some error

The same project is working on **ubuntu** system but when i clone this code on **mac** system and try to run npm install it failed with some error

**I think there is something with scrypt module but i do't know the reason exactly 
Please help me, Thanks in advance**

OS: MAC 
Node: 10.15
Npm :6.0

**See error below :-**

```
WareWolf:mynodeapp$ npm install
> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
configure: error: /node_modules/scrypt/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

> scrypt@6.0.3 install /node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.34.0/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.34.0/versions/node/v10.15.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.34.0/versions/node/v10.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
```

Comment: Did you “See `config.log' for more details”? What does it say? It's trying to compile a module written in C. Perhaps you need to update Xcode (shot in the dark, I'm not an expert on this)

Comment: Please post config.log

Comment: where is config.log?

Comment: **npm install** worked when i removed **node_modules** file but i do't know what was the problem => i forgot to put  node_modules file in .gitignore file.. earlier i was using ubuntu and when i git clone repo in mac system, tried to run npm install it starts throwing error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will need to remove `package-lock.json`, `.npm` and `node_modules` folder.

Required steps:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
npm cache clean — force
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf node_modules
rm -f package-lock.json
```

In npm install .staging issue, When you run npm install, it creates the node_modules folder but all the modules go into a subfolder called .staging

Answer (score 2):

I have found the same issue when I started a project in my linux machine and I like to clone to work on it from a Mac.

Solution working for me:

`npm install --no-optional`

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071650/2976796

The other way to solve this, is to remove the package-lock.json.