# how to solve the npm installation error fsevents 1 and fsevents 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js

npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

i was following a tutorial from traversary media npm crash course and i was trying to download gulp gulp--sass and i got that error msg

Comment: Please provide exact error that you’re seeing when attempting to do the upgrade. This way we can help, right now we don’t know what you have tried so far.

Comment: i was following a tutorial from traversary media npm crash course and i was trying to download gulp gulp--sass and i got that error msg

Comment: nodejs version yu're using ?

Comment: try this npm install fsevents@latest

Comment: v13.1.0 this the version i'm using at the moment

Comment: after running npm install@latest i got:                                                                  $ npm install fsevents@latest
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\steph\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T01_43_37_288Z-debug.log

Comment: npm version yu're using ?

Comment: are you sure you're getting an error when using original package in initial question?. It specifically says it's a warning that will become a problem once you are in node14 which you currently are not. If you want to upgrade, then install latest gulp rather than trying to fix the warning package separately. Since there could be breaking changes when you install peer dependencies separately.

Comment: my npm version is 6.12.1
my node.js version is v13.1.0                                                                                       npm install gulp gulp-sass --save-dev; i ran this intially

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve npm install throwing fsevents warning on non-MAC OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929196/how-to-solve-npm-install-throwing-fsevents-warning-on-non-mac-os)

Answer (score -3):

```
$: npm install -g fsevents@2.1.3
```

Comment: Please explain your