# React.js - warnings & errors while using "npx create-react-app" command

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I get some warnings and errors messages when try to create a react.js app using the command `npx creat-react-app`

here is the terminal output containing the errors I get. also I wanna specify that when the react.js app is created regardless of these errors it's actually working. but I'm afraid of that if there is something missing. Node.js and all of the required tools are installed as well.

Node.js version: LTS Version 12.18.4 (includes npm 6.14.6)

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder
λ npx create-react-app my-app

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.3
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react@16.13.1
added 1598 packages from 746 contributors and audited 1602 packages in 65.645s

69 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


Initialized a git repository.

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ @testing-library/user-event@7.2.1
+ @testing-library/jest-dom@4.2.4
+ @testing-library/react@9.5.0
added 36 packages from 57 contributors and audited 1638 packages in 13.978s

69 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1 package and audited 1637 packages in 10.641s

69 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Git commit not created Error: Command failed: git commit -m "Initialize project using Create React App"
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
    at tryGitCommit (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:62:5)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:334:25)
    at [eval]:3:14
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
  status: 128,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 1532,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Removing .git directory...

Success! Created my-app at C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cmder\my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  npm start
    Starts the development server.

  npm run build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  npm test
    Starts the test runner.

  npm run eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  npm start

Happy hacking!
```

Comment: I also have the same problem, in my case, I just had to configure git identity with:
git config --global user.name <yourName>
git config --global user.email <yourEmail>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Git commit not created Error: Command failed: git commit -m
> "Initialize project using Create React App"

Seems like you don't have git installed. Install git if you want cra to initialize a git repository. If you don't plan on using git, you should just ignore the error.

> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

This is an optional dependency for mac (darwin)

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929196/how-to-solve-npm-install-throwing-fsevents-warning-on-non-mac-os) points out that you can use `npm install --no-optional` to prevent warning from happening.

> npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Seems like cra use typescript and ask you to install a version a typescript above 2.8.0.

`npm i -g typescript`

should solve the problem